# filter by key in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to filter by key in javascript.

I have a ajax function , on passing id, will result `obj1` in success one after other.
I would like to combine all results by `key` and push to single object.
How to do the following in javascript.

```
var id =["trans", "fund"]
setTimeout(()=>{
      id.map((e)=>this.static(e))
    }, 2000)

static(id){
var li = $.ajax({
           url: "/en",
          method: 'get',
          global: false,
          async: false,
          data: {
            providers: id
          },
          success: function (data) {
            return data;
          }
        }).responseText;
  var obj1=data; //I need to combine and store data in expected output format
}


//on first call
var obj1={
  country: "SG",
  trans: [{
    rate: 20,
    members: 100
  }]
}
//on second call
var obj1={
  country: "TH",
  fund: [{
    rate: 20,
    members: 100
  }]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
var result ={
  trans: [{
    rate: 20,
    members: 100
  }],
  fund: [{
    rate: 20,
    members: 100
  }]
}
```

Comment: May be you want merge this two objects?

Comment: how is obj1 being stored on each successive call? will it replace its previous value?

Comment: can you clear the question?

Comment: @Harish updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var id =["trans", "fund"];
var result = {};
//on first call
var obj1={
    country: "SG",
    trans: [{
        rate: 20,
        members: 100
    }]
}
result = getObj(result,obj1);
//on second call
var obj1={
    country: "TH",
    fund: [{
        rate: 20,
        members: 100
    }]
}
result = getObj(result,obj1);
console.log(result);

function getObj(result,obj){
    for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        if (obj[id[i]]) {
            result[id[i]] =  obj[id[i]];
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this. I assume your keys are fixed. click on the [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/yyDDqWIFHgW7N3NcIREs/) for demo.

```
  var output = {};
  var id = ["trans", "fund"]

  //on first call
  var obj1 = {
    country: "SG",
    trans: [{
      rate: 20,
      members: 100
    }]
  }
  //on second call
  var obj2 = {
    country: "TH",
    fund: [{
      rate: 20,
      members: 100
    }]
  }

  function getObj(selectedId) {
    console.log(id); // global variable.
    if(!id) return;

    id.forEach(x => {
      let obj1Key = obj1[x];
      if (obj1Key) output[x] = obj1Key;

      let obj2Key = obj2[x];
      if (obj2Key) output[x] = obj2Key;
    })
   console.log('output object', output);
   console.log('JSON:', JSON.stringify(output));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below, this will the merge the values if result already have the values

```
//
 var id =["trans", "fund"];
 var result = {};

 function getObj(obj){
   id.map(val => {
      if(result[val]) { result[val] = [...result[val], ...obj[val]]}
      else result[val] = obj[val]
   })
 }

//on first call
    var obj1={
      country: "SG",
      trans: [{
        rate: 20,
        members: 100
      }]
    }
    getObj(obj1)
/*
{
  trans: [{
    rate: 20,
    members: 100
  }]
}
*/

    //on second call
    var obj1={
      country: "TH",
      fund: [{
        rate: 20,
        members: 100
      }]
    }
getObj(obj2)
/*
{
  trans: [{
    rate: 20,
    members: 100
   }],
   fund: [{
     rate: 20,
     members: 100
   }]
}
*/
```